# Animation Nodes can Not be enabled and also can not be deleted

Tags: add-on, animation-nodes

Animation Nodes addon (Jacques Lucke Version 2.1.4 ) can Not be enabled in Blender 2,82a and also can not be deleted There is an exclamation mark icon inside triangle and it says `line 351 in eneble mod`.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version installed : https://animation-nodes.com/#download and check the common issues : https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/1240

Comment: So, I've added DLL as suggested and WOW it works, I can not believe it, Thanx a million!

Comment: No problem ! Have fun